# How do I pick the lowest cost value for each category?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I have two lists that have the same number of elements. In the first list, an element represents a category type. In the second list, an element represents a kind of cost. Indices corresponds to each other.

For example:

```
category_list = [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2]
cost_list = [30, 45, 21, 22, 21, 32, 11, 12, 13, 11]
```

On the condition that I pick one for every category, I would like to minimize the cost. How can I implement this? Faster, better. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the minimum cost of each category in a `dict`.

```
category_list = [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2]
cost_list = [30, 45, 21, 22, 21, 32, 11, 12, 13, 11]

min_cst = dict()
for cat, cst in zip(category_list, cost_list):
    if cat in min_cst:
        min_cst[cat] = min(min_cst[cat], cst)
    else:
        min_cst[cat] = cst

print(min_cst)
# {1: 22, 2: 11, 3: 11, 4: 13}
```

The time complexity is `O(N)` and space complexity is `O(N)`.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I learned when to use dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

I recommended this code. In here we use the prebuilt method 'zip' in python to iteratively get the category_list and cost_list so I supposed it is good practice and then I using conditional expression to create my logic. First I want to determine in that category already in my x_dict in that expression is true I using 'min' prebuilt method to compare the value that already exists and the new value of the related key. So it is helpful to manage our logic. Otherwise, that key does not already exist then we can added key-value pair for the first time. the dictionary key is must be unique that's why we using this logic.

```
category_list = [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2]
cost_list = [30, 45, 21, 22, 21, 32, 11, 12, 13, 11]
x_dict=dict()
for cat,cost in zip(category_list,cost_list):
    if cat in x_dict:
        x_dict[cat]=min(x_dict[cat],cost)
    else:
        x_dict[cat]=cost


print(x_dict)
```

Output

> {1: 22, 2: 11, 3: 11, 4: 13}

We can use the zip method directly and convert it to the dictionary. It can filter the unique keys but the case is it given the last value for the related key which we use like given below.

```
x=dict(zip(category_list,cost_list))
print(x)
```

output

> {1: 22, 2: 11, 3: 12, 4: 13}

You can see last cost of the given list assign to the related category. Thats we give that logic for our code.

Comment: Thank you for your solutions and some tips about zip function.

Comment: My solution included that one..You can see there are 4 categories and minimum values of that {1: 22, 2: 11, 3: 11, 4: 13}. This is a dictionary data structure. If you want to get minimum cost one by one you can code this way. print(f'1st category minimum cost is {x[1]}'. You get other categories cost also this way. Is anything to clarify?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**:

You can iterate over `category_list` and save a min of `cost_list` in a dictionary that key is `category_list` and you can use `dictionary.get()` and replace min with the minimum that exist before in the dictionary.

```
category_list = [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2]
cost_list = [30, 45, 21, 22, 21, 32, 11, 12, 13, 11]

dct_min = {}
for idx in range(len(category_list)):
    min_item = dct_min.get(category_list[idx], cost_list[idx])
    # alternative solution by thanks @Stef
    # min_item = dct_min.setdefault(category_list[idx], cost_list[idx]); if cost_list[idx] < min_item: ...
    if cost_list[idx] <= min_item:
        dct_min[category_list[idx]] = cost_list[idx]
print(dct_min)
```

Output:

```
{1: 22, 2: 11, 3: 11, 4: 13}
```

**Solution 2**: *(you can use `zip` then sort `tuple` first base `index0` then `index1` and convert sorted `tuple` to `dictionary` and we know in `dictionary` we have only one `key`.)*

```
zip_lsts = list(zip(category_list, cost_list))
dict(sorted(zip_lsts, key=lambda element: (element[0], element[1]),reverse=True))
# {4: 13, 3: 11, 2: 11, 1: 22}
```

Comment: Alternatively `min_item = dct_min.setdefault(category_list[idx], cost_list[idx]); if cost_list[idx] < min_item: ...`

Comment: @Stef thanks a lot, you are so nice ;) edited answer

Comment: Note the `get` and `setdefault` lines are not equivalent; the solution with `get` requires `<=` on the next line, whereas with `setdefault` you can have `<` on the next line.

Comment: Thank you for your solutions. Learned the difference between get and setdefault  method. So useful.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are already three nearly-identical answers using `dict`, here is a different answer using `min` only once per category:

```py
category_list  = [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2]
cost_list      = [30, 45, 21, 22, 21, 32, 11, 12, 13, 11]

pick_indices   = [min((i for i in range(len(cost_list)) if category_list[i] == cat), key=lambda i: cost_list[i]) for cat in set(category_list)]
pick_totalcost = sum(cost_list[i] for i in pick_indices)
```

Or alternatively:

```py
pick_costs     = [min(cost for i,(cost,cat) in enumerate(zip(cost_list, category_list)) if cat == c) for c in set(category_list)]
pick_totalcost = sum(pick_costs)
```

Comment: Thank you for your alternative solutions. Took a while to understand your code:-)

Comment: @agongji  Sorry, I should have included an explanation along with the code! I was lazy yesterday.